# Podio Age Calculation

Tags: podio

My organisation has a Podio calculation field (see code below) to calculate the age of a person.

In order to get this field to update daily (because we need up to date data), the associated field @Date Today is updated with a Globiflow flow with today's date.

At the moment, there are ~1800 records and growing. So if this is run every day we are going way over the limits set by Globiflow (http://www.globiflow.com/help/globiflow-plans-and-limits.php).

Any ideas on more elegant ways to achieve this without using up our workflows? Essentially I need to calculate the age of each person, each day.

JS in Podio 'Age' field:

```
var date = @Date Of Birth; 
var dateCalc = moment(date); 
var currentDate = moment(@Date Today); 
var calc = currentDate.diff(dateCalc, 'y','m');
date != null ? calc : null
```

Thanks
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to have an app with single item to keep the today's date. Update this single item everyday using GlobiFlow with today's date.

This item should be referred in all the 1800 Person items. Now use the today date from this single item in age calculation in person app. You can have a GlobiFlow to refer this single item automatically when ever a new Person is created.